# How to configure the submit button so that it can submit the form that has been validated?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, submit

I'm having a problem where Once I put "return validation()" in my submit button, The button won't submit. But the validation is working fine. Is there anyway to bypass this so that javascript can validate my file and then submit the form?

This is my javascript:

```
function validate()
{

    var username = document.getElementById("name");
    var img = document.getElementById("image");


    if(username.value.trim()=="")
    {
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("error");
        myDiv.innerHTML = "Username Not Entered";
    }

    else if (img.value.trim()=="")

    {
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("error");
        myDiv.innerHTML = "Please Select an image";
    }

    return false;


}


</script>
```

And this is my html, When I put return in front of

```
        <div class="add-form">
            <h1 class="text-center"><font face="fantasy">Please Insert new image</font></h1>
            <form onSubmit = "validate()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="FormID">
                <label>User Name</label>
                <input id = "name" type="text" name="user_name" class="form-control">
                <label>Select image to upload</label>
                <input id = "image" type="file"  onchange ="unlock()" name="profile" class="form-control2" accept="*/image">
                <button type="submit" value = "submit" name="btn-add">upload</button>
                <div id = "error">Please fill up the username and select and image</div>

            </form>
        </div>
        <hr style="border-bottom: 5px blue solid;">
    </div> 
<!-- end form insert -->
<!-- view form -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="view-form">
        <div class="row">
        <?php 
            $stmt=$db_conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_user ORDER BY id DESC');
                $stmt->execute();
                if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
                {
                    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        extract($row);
                        ?>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['picprofile']?>"><br><br>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="edit_form.php?edit_id=<?php echo $row['id']?>" title="click for edit" onlick="return confirm('Sure to edit this record')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicone-edit"></span>Edit</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="?delete_id=<?php echo $row['id']?>" title="click for delete">Delete</a>

            </div>

            <?php 

                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- end view form -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable inside the `validate` function and submit the form only in case of valid data:

```
function validate()
{
    var username = document.getElementById("name");
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("error");

    let valid = true;

    if(username.value.trim()=="")
    {
        myDiv.innerHTML = "Username Not Entered";

        valid = false;
    }
    else if (img.value.trim()=="")
    {
        myDiv.innerHTML = "Please Select an image";

        valid = false;
    }

    if(valid)
    {
        document.getElementById('FormID').submit();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also change the `<'form` and the `<button` lines to this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="FormID">
...
<button type="submit" value = "submit" name="btn-add" onClick = "validate()">upload</button>
```

Comment: When I press the upload button, The validation only appears for a split second, And then it reloads.

Comment: @MuhammadNurAmjadh did you make all changes I suggested?

Comment: Yup, Only for a few seconds and then it reloads and it submits blank images. I found out that if i put "return validate()" at form or button, It does work but the problem is that the images that I am uploading are not showing in my database nor my folder.

Comment: @MuhammadNurAmjadh that may be another problem/question, please post a new question, I'll try yo help you. The validation seems solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
<form onSubmit = "return validate()"
```

And also you need to wrap `return false` in the if cases like:

```
function validate()
{

    var username = document.getElementById("name");
    var img = document.getElementById("image");


    if(username.value.trim()=="") {
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("error");
        myDiv.innerHTML = "Username Not Entered";
        return false;
    }
    else if (img.value.trim()=="") {
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("error");
        myDiv.innerHTML = "Please Select an image";
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't enough because `validate()` returns always `false`

Comment: Your right. I answered too fast, because I've seen the onsubmit event didn't return.
So, it's right to wrap return false into the if clause.I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: There are always some ways to achieve a solution. In my opinion this solution is quite simple and clean.

Comment: Maybe you're true :)

Comment: You're welcome. :) And please accept it as answer ;)